# Selenium- TestNG

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng-dataprovider

I am trying to write a Excel Reading program, but for in static manner.
When I run this program through TestNG, it throws an Exception- "argument type mismatch".

Please suggest me, where I went wrong.

```
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Dummy_Excel_Reading
{

    @Test(dataProvider="getdata")
    public void test(String username, Integer Number, String Address)
    {
        System.out.println(username +" - "+ Number +" - "+ Address);
    }


    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] getdata() 
    {
        Object[][] data=new Object[2][3];

        data[0][0]="Abcd";
        data[0][1]="123";
        data[0][2]="Noida";

        data[1][0]="Xyz";
        data[1][1]="789";
        data[1][2]="Delhi";

        return data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You store number as a String in the Object array but you expect an Integer in the test method.

`public void test(String username, Integer Number, String Address)`

Change it like this

`data[0][1]=123;`

`data[1][1]=789;`

Comment: Thanks Vinoth S :)

Comment: @PrashantAgarwal, You can accept it as answer by clicking on the tick sign if it helped